# Как сделать отступ слева CSS?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сделать такой `header`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задний фон — картинка. Текст — ссылка на главную страницу сайта.

У меня получался такой `header`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить отступ слева для текста ссылки?

Мой код html

```
<body>
<div id ="main">
    <div id ="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html"><p>Мой первый простой сайт</p></a></h1>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#header{
height: 90px;
background: #2a79bc url("images/header.png") no-repeat; 
}

#header h1{
font-size: 28px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding: 20px, 0, 0, 20px;
color: #ff5500;
}
#header h1 a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 100;
letter-spacing: -2px;
margin-left: 100px;
}
#header h1 a:hover {
color: #111;
}

#header h1 a p {
margin-left: 10px;
padding-left: 100px;
}
```

С помощью добавления абзаца в ссылку удалось опустить ее ниже, но отступ слева сделать не получается.

Теперь мой код выглядит так

Html:

```
    <div id ="header">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Мой первый простой сайт</a></h1>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#header{
height: 90px;
background: #2a79bc url("images/header.png") no-repeat; 
}

#header h1{
font-size: 28px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
color: #ff5500;
}
 #header h1 a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 100;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 }
 #header h1 a:hover {
 color: #111;
 }


a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #4682B4;
}

a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
color: #2a52be;
}
```

Вот скрин с сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите тег p из ссылки, а отступы пропишите
`padding: 20px 0 0 20px;` то есть, уберите запятые.

PS, чтобы всё работало. пишите так:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="header">
    <h1><a href="index.html">
      Мой первый простой сайт
    </a></h1>
  </div>
</div>

#header {
  height: 90px;
  background: #2a79bc url("images/header.png") no-repeat;
}

#header h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  color: #ff5500;
}

#header h1 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  //margin-left: 100px;
}

#header h1 a:hover {
  color: #111;
}
```

Comment: тег p убрал, запятые тоже. Отступа слева не появилось

Comment: Покажите как теперь выглядит код? Кстати. может это только так скопировалось при перенесении кода сюда, но у вас один div (тот, что main) не закрыт.

Comment: Не закрыт, потому, что я только часть кода скопировал. Сейчас покажу, как выглядит код.

Comment: обновил свой вопрос

Comment: @Konstantin_SH я обновил свой ответ. Сравните код с вашим. Обратите внимание на то, что одну строку я закомментировал - в ней отступ переопределялся, а стиль для параграфа и вовсе снёс.

Comment: Скопировал Ваш код себе. Отступа нет.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH на ваш сайт можно где-то посмотреть? Я имею в виду. выложен ли он на каком-то хостинге? Код рабочий, можно посмотреть https://jsfiddle.net/mLwduqbc/

Comment: @Konstantin_SH  вам вот так надо ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RwPZgJE

Comment: @Quazimorda Мой сайт https://konstantinshirmanov.github.io/FirstSitOnDivBlocks/

Comment: @Konstantin_SH у вас ссылка это inline-block а параграф это block, удалите параграф из ссылки

Comment: @Konstantin_SH По указанной вами ссылке параграф из тега "a" никуда не делся. Как был, так и есть.

Comment: @Quazimorda Странно. У меня ссылка подпрыгнула выше. Отступа нет. Могу скрин дать

Comment: Всё верно ..вы удалил блок из инлайна ..теперя удалите line-height

Comment: @Konstantin_SH по данной вами ссылке на сайт в padding до сих пор есть запятые и поэтому отступы не срабатывают как нужно.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH а Теперь отступ слева равен 30 пикселям, так как к 20, что указаны в селекторе #header h1 добавились ещё 10 из селектора #header h1 a. Будьте осторожны. ))

Comment: @Quazimorda разобрался вроде, спасибо за терпение))

Comment: @Konstantin_SH из всего вышеописанного можно сделать вывод - всегда проще что-то подсказать, если виден именно тот код, который у вас не работает. И раз уж сайт где-то уже опубликован - давайте ссылки на проблемные места.